# show and hide div on an onclick event bypassing a onblur event in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a textfield that uses an onblur event to format numbers in currency. I want to run my onclick function that hides a div on form first before the blur values are taken. Problem is every time I click in the field div does not disappear and when I run my values in formula after blur then don't calculate. I had added an alert function in the on blur function and the alert message was looping. I looking for a show hide div function everytime I click in the textfield.

```
 <input name="txtA" type="text" id="txtA" value="<?php  if(isset($_POST['calculate'])){ echo 'R '.number_format($_SESSION['salesprice'],2);}else { echo $_SESSION['salesprice']; } ?>" size="50" onblur="this.value = 'R ' + formatNumber(this.value, 0, 0, true);" onclick = "return document.getElementById('linkContainer2').innerHTML = myFunction();"  />


       <br />
<div id="linkContainer2">My Content</div>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    divTest = document.getElementById('linkContainer2');
    if (divTest.style.display === "none") {
        divTest.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        divTest.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not an answer, but something that might help you debug. The alert was probably looping because the alert popup was stealing focus and triggering the blur event. If you instead do a console.log, I don't think you'll see the looping.

Comment: To clarify.. you have a textbox and a div. When the user enters the textbox, you want to hide the div. They edit the text, then when they leave the textbox you want to format the text and show the div again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is difficult to follow, as you're combining PHP, HTML, and JavaScript all into one big pile. Instead, I've separated each language for you:

```
<?php
    $value = $_SESSION['salesprice'];
    if (isset($_POST['calculate'])) $value = number_format($_SESSION['salesprice'], 2);
?>


<input id="txtA" name="txtA" type="text" value="<?=$value;?>" size="50" />
<br />
<div id="linkContainer2">My Content</div>


<script>
    String.prototype.formatCurrency = function(c, d, t) {
        var n = this.replace(/[,\$]/g,''), 
        c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, 
        d = d == undefined ? "." : d, 
        t = t == undefined ? "," : t, 
        s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", 
        i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", 
        j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
        return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
     };



    Element.prototype.addEvent = function(eventName, callFunction) {
      if (this.addEventListener) this.addEventListener(eventName.substring(2), callFunction, false);
      else if (this.attachEvent) this.attachEvent(eventName, callFunction);
    };



    function get(el) {
        if (el) {
            if (typeof el === 'string' || !isNaN(el)) {
                if (el == 'document.body') return document.body;
                return document.getElementById(el);
            }
            else {
                if (el.id) {
                    if (document.getElementById(el.id)) return document.getElementById(el.id);
                    else if (typeof el == '') return el;
                }
                else return el;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }




get('txtA').addEvent('onfocus', function() {
    get('linkContainer2').style.display = 'none';
});


get('txtA').addEvent('onblur', function() {
    this.value = '$' + this.value.formatCurrency(2, '.', ',');
});

</script>
```

You can view this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/6okLLg6k/

---

As a bonus, I have a few pointers that may be helpful:

1. You were setting the `innerHTML` of `linkContainer2` to = `myFunction`. In theory that's fine, but in your case `myFunction` always returns nothing. So in other words, you were setting it to nothing.
2. Inside `myFunction`, you were setting its `innerHTML` again. This makes me think we can accomplish everything you want without `myFunction`.
3. Instead of `onclick`, I'm using `onfocus`. This should have the same effect, but also capture when the tab key is used to enter your textbox.
4. I've separated your PHP, HTML, and JavaScript into 3 distinct sections. I know it can seem like a waste of time, but investing that tiny extra time makes your life easier in the long run. Debugging problems like this takes half as long. I highly recommend writing your projects this way in the future.
5. I wasn't sure why you were toggling the display of `linkContainer2`, so I just made its `display` always `= none`. You can add back your if statement, if it was necessary.
6. I've included in some extra JavaScript functionality which you may find useful. My `get` function replaces `document.getElementById`, making your code easier to read. I also included `addEvent`, and `formatCurrency`, which should also make your life easier.

Comment: It works thanks for the help. Pointers are noted (",)